# docker registry frontend (konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend) getting error when clicked on repository and also docker images are not seen

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image]I am using docker registry frontend (konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend), when i browser the repository i am getting following error(attached image) when clicked on repository and also docker images are not seen in UI. Below is the dockercompose file which I am using.

```
---
version: '3'

services:
    docker-registry:
        container_name: docker-registry
        image: registry:2
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./volume:/var/lib/registry
    docker-registry-ui:
        container_name: docker-registry-ui
        image: konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
        links:
            - docker-registry:docker-registry
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST: docker-registry
            ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT: 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Please open an issue here, so we can keep track of it, okay? https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend/issues/new

Also, please have a look at this document: https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend/tree/v2/example-setup to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I have created private docker registry with username and password, but problem is dependencies docker images are not pulling by default. Eg: I am trying to pull docker image 2 with had dependencies on docker image 1. If i pull docker image 2 directly it says unknown blob. If i try to pull docker image 1 and then docker image 2 it works fine.

Comment: Is there an issue for this on github?

Comment: In docker image A= used base image as ubuntu and installed java and in docker image B = used based image as docker image A and installed apache. Both docker images A and B are present in private docker repository. But after server restarts when I try to pull docker image B it throws an error as Unknown blob. Any solution would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Related to this issue probably: https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend/issues/20

Speculated solution is to add link in UI section (service:env_variable) as:

```
links:
        - docker-registry:docker-registry
```

Comment: GET http://192.168.120.89:8080/v2/_catalog?n=20&last= 502 (Proxy Error). Something related to proxy issue I am facing but not sure how to solve it. Please guide me

Comment: Could you prune your old images. I tried that compose file, and it worked straight. Or are you using VPN or something else, which could change your network?

Comment: It's also weird that your IP is  192.168.120.89, where are you running it?

Comment: yeah i am using VPN. Even i tired to running compose file in another file it worked. But not sure what is the error in that server

Comment: it is working now the issue was ssl certificate due to this proxy error was coming

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with (latest) registry and konradkleine (v2) registry-frontend.
Button Browse Repositories directs to the port where registry frontend is running.

In my case i have access to the registry-frontend from:
https://192.168.1.105:31652/home

And button Browse Repositories try redirect from:
https://192.168.1.105:31652/repositories/20

to

https://192.168.1.105:31652/v2/_catalog?n=20&last=

but this resource is available at:

192.168.1.105:5000/v2/_catalog?n=20&last=

in effect i receive:

**GET https://192.168.1.105:31652/v2/_catalog?n=20&last= 503 (Service Unavailable)**

Comment: I solved my problem by recreating ssl certificate due to this proxy error